# Google storage image not loading in Android by Glide, Picasso or Universal Image Loader

Tags: android

https://storage.cloud.google.com/vg-img-bucket/istockphoto-1016218444-170667a.jpg

This is the image url, which I have tried Glide, Picasso or Universal Image Loader, here is the method for glide, which I am using. This image is opening in chrome.

```
@BindingAdapter(value = {"android:src", "placeholderImage", "errorImage"}, requireAll = false)
public static void loadImageWithGlide(ImageView imageView, Object src, Object placeholder, Object errorImage) {
    if (src == null) {
        if (placeholder != null) {
            if (placeholder instanceof Drawable)
                imageView.setImageDrawable((Drawable) placeholder);
            if (placeholder instanceof Integer)
                imageView.setImageResource((Integer) placeholder);
        }
        return;
    }

    RequestOptions options = new RequestOptions();
    options = options.diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE);

    if (placeholder != null) {
        if (placeholder instanceof Drawable) options.placeholder((Drawable) placeholder);
        if (placeholder instanceof Integer) options.placeholder((Integer) placeholder);
    }
    if (errorImage != null) {
        if (errorImage instanceof Drawable) options.error((Drawable) errorImage);
        if (errorImage instanceof Integer) options.error((Integer) errorImage);
    }

    RequestManager manager = Glide.with(App.getInstance()).
            applyDefaultRequestOptions(options);
    RequestBuilder<Drawable> builder;

    if (src instanceof String) {
        builder = manager.load((String) src);
    } else if (src instanceof Uri)
        builder = manager.load((Uri) src);
    else if (src instanceof Drawable)
        builder = manager.load((Drawable) src);
    else if (src instanceof Bitmap)
        builder = manager.load((Bitmap) src);
    else if (src instanceof Integer)
        builder = manager.load((Integer) src);
    else if (src instanceof File)
        builder = manager.load((File) src);
    else if (src instanceof byte[])
        builder = manager.load((byte[]) src);
    else builder = manager.load(src);
    builder.into(imageView);
}
```

Here is the error -

```
2020-07-22 21:23:34.045 21752-21752/com.tiffin31 W/Glide: Load failed for https://storage.cloud.google.com/vg-img-bucket/istockphoto-1016218444-170667a.jpg with size [211x211]
    class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed to load resource
      Cause (1 of 1): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed LoadPath{ContentLengthInputStream->Object->Drawable}, REMOTE
        Cause (1 of 3): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed DecodePath{ContentLengthInputStream->GifDrawable->Drawable}
        Cause (2 of 3): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed DecodePath{ContentLengthInputStream->Bitmap->Drawable}
        Cause (3 of 3): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed DecodePath{ContentLengthInputStream->BitmapDrawable->Drawable}
```

Comment: When I clicked on the link, after the image has rendered, the URL was different. Like the link requires some kind of key

Comment: Yes, that can be a reason.

Comment: You need an active Google account in the used device. If not log in first.

Comment: @blackapps yes I have logged in already

Comment: Best way is to check with chrome Dev tools to see if the URL accepts a unique key